# Trying to destroy a model, saying wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure why I am getting this error:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

app/models/user.rb:38:in `sign_out_by_guid'
app/helpers/user_helper.rb:11:in `sign_out'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:18:in `destroy'
```

My code:

```
def self.sign_out_by_guid(guid)
    puts 'currently in sign_out_by_guid' + guid
    u = User.where("guid = ?", guid) 
    puts u.inspect
    puts 'before destroy'
    u.destroy
    puts 'called destroy'
  end
```

I can see all the puts output expect for the last one "called destroy"

So this means for sure the call to `u.destroy` is the issue.

If I try getting a record in `rails console`, and calling destroy on the user it works fine.

What could this be?

Answer (score 13):

`u` is a collection of `User`s, but [`destroy`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-destroy) needs to be called on a single user, or on a [relation with an argument denoting the ID](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy) of the `User`. You can either do:

```
u = User.where("guid = ?", guid).first
```

or

```
u = User.find_by_guid(guid)
```

Answer (score 0):

check user.rb.
make sure your params is

```
dependent: :destroy
```

not

```
dependent: destroy
```